# How adjust label alignment using autolayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have some labels on my screen.4 Labels can have dynamic value it can display integer number  value as well as it can also display some word as **START**.I have given the following constraints:

- Leading to image
- Top to image

[image]

Now as the text increase there is enough space on left so that label can expand it's width.but as i have given leading to top image so it will not move more to left.So please tell how can i move it to left when text increase.I know i can do it with the help of making outlet of leading constraint and change its value.
But is there any easy way of doing it ?

Comment: If you have set leading space to image so you can set its relation i believe right now it is equal relation,make it less than relation and try.

Comment: If i try less or greater then then i see conflication in constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the leading Constraints to "less than equal to" '<=' and trailing fixed '=', whenever the label will have lengthier text its size will increase in the left side and be fixed on the right side

[image]

Comment: why not greater than equal & why only less than euqal?

Comment: it works if there is only one label but i have two lables in same line in that case label first s shifting towards out in left from screen

Comment: the constraint <= means that the value of the constrain will be lesser than the given constant e.g: 259 if needed, so if the label size increases the constrain value will decrease on that side and if it is greater than then the constrain will increase its value